# How can I make a gif and two rows of text line up inside an enclosing div?

Tags: html, css

I have the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYkBC/)

There's an image of 32 by 32 on the left and two lines of text on the right. Can someone have a look at this and tell me where I am going wrong. All I need is for the center of the gif and the text to line up with the middle of the enclosing frame.

As you will see from the fiddle I tried quite a few different combinations of margin but none seem to work for me.

Is the problem because I am using "display: inline-block;" or are there other problems?

```
<div class="server-info">
   <div style="z-index: 99; width: 32px; height: 32px;
      margin-top: 9px;
      margin-bottom: 9px;
      margin-right: 3px; display: inline-block;" id="load-icon"></div>
   <div style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 5px; height: 40px;">XXX<br>YYY </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.server-info {
    border-radius: 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em;
    border-top: 0 none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 1.6em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: none;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
}

#load-icon
{
    background: url("http://www.smilecarwash.com/images/ajax-loader.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**Update**: Corrected fiddle link - sorry about that

Comment: wer is the gif image in the fiddle?

Comment: still not seeing any gif

Comment: Aparently the fiddle has nothing to do with this question...

Comment: agree with @arkascha fiddle is entirely different than your shown code here

Comment: wait I will fork the fiddle and update the link. Everything shows on my version.

Comment: @SamanthaJ thats fine.. Did u check my answer and is that wat u need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/BcPjz/4/

To align vertically middle you need to add `display:table-cell` and `vertical middle` to the text div.

Or this http://jsfiddle.net/GYkBC/1/

To place the text below the image add `display:block` to either image div or text div

Comment: Great work. You solved in a few minutes something I have spent more than an hour on. Thanks so much !  I will mark as accepted. Maybe for helping others do you think you can explain in your answer the thing you did. Looks to me like you're adding display: inline-table;
 was what fixed it.